# Difference between skewness formulas

Tags: skewness, kurtosis

I recently started learning statistics. I got problem while learning skewness & kurtosis concept i.e in my search for formulas regarding skewness & kurtosis it is showing two different formulas and don't understand when to use which.

[image: skewness@1]
[image: skewness@2]

And the same problem for kurtosis is also having when to use lengthy formula and when to use small.

Can any one please give me clarification?

Comment: Check out Joanes, D. N., & Gill, C. A. (1998). Comparing measures of sample skewness and kurtosis. The statistician, 183-189.

Answer (score 1):

Different estimators of skewness and kurtosis result in different equations being used. However, for adequate sample sizes they shouldn't deviate much. This is further discussed [here](http://www.spcforexcel.com/knowledge/basic-statistics/are-skewness-and-kurtosis-useful-statistics)

Comment: These aren't different *definitions*: they are different *estimators* of the same quantity.